# Get the filepath of the file being accessed by a window using JNA with Java

Tags: java, windows, jna, filepath

I am using JNA with Java to find some properties about open windows on a Windows machine desktop.  I am trying to find a way to get the file being accessed by an arbitrary windowed application.  For instance, say I get information regarding the window of an open pdf document in adobe.  I want to be able to get the filepath of the pdf document displayed in the window.

I know about the GetWindowModuleFileName() method, however this gets you the filepath of the executable of the application, i.e. 'javaw.exe'.  If you have 'my.pdf' open in adobe, I'd like to get the filepath of this document, i.e. 'C:\...\my.pdf'.

I've done some searching around (on this site and others) and haven't found anything yet on this in particular.

thank you for your time, -Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the process ID, you can get the list of all files currently opened by the process using [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) utility. However, it depends if adobe reader continues to keep the file open or closes it after reading it completely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am finding the utility very useful.  After a few days of experimenting and looking around I have a quick follow up question.  With the PID, you can get a full list of the files being accessed, 'handle -p PID'.  Is it possible to isolate the file opened in programs such as adobe or word, etc i.e. 'my.pdf, my.docx' from all of the other ones listed by the utility?  I'm trying to write a program that uses this information, so I'm looking for a way to isolate this filepath.

Comment: @kevin: I think you need to parse the output of handle utility and extract the information you require.