# Getting a list of files currently opened in Microsoft Word

Tags: java, ms-word, jna

I am trying to get a list of all currently opened documents/files in Microsoft Word within a Java desktop application.  I am already using JNA to get running processes and the associated window titles, but the API does not provide enough information about the actual opened files (or is there a way with JNA to list all files currently used by a process, but not using external tools like [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670737/get-the-filepath-of-the-file-being-accessed-by-a-window-using-jna-with-java)?).

In C#, one way to do this is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892018/c-sharp-get-list-of-opened-word-documents). But I honestly don't know how I could reuse this answer within a Java application. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: You will have to use JNI or a web service to talk to some native code.

Comment: Thanks, building a .Net-Service is a neat idea, I look into that. I am also going to check out [bridj](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/).

Comment: You probably want to use some COM variant; you could attach to the MS word process and use COM functions to query for application details.  Once you've figured out how to do it with native code, then you can move on to figure out how to call that native code with tool X, Y, or Z.